# Drop the rows in front by conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

`df`:

```
       Id      timestamp                data    Date         sig    event1 Start    End    Timediff2   datadiff2    B
51253   51494   2020-01-27 06:22:08.330 19.5    2020-01-27   -1.0   0.0     NaN     1.0     NaN          NaN        NaN
51254   51495   2020-01-27 06:22:08.430 19.0    2020-01-27   1.0    1.0     0.0     0.0     0.1          NaN        NaN
51255   51496   2020-01-27 07:19:06.297 19.5    2020-01-27   1.0    0.0     1.0     0.0     3417.967     0.0        0.000000
51256   51497   2020-01-27 07:19:06.397 20.0    2020-01-27   1.0    0.0     0.0     0.0     0.1          1.0        0.000293
51259   51500   2020-01-27 07:32:19.587 20.5    2020-01-27   1.0    0.0     0.0     1.0     793.290      1.0        0.001261
```

I have 2 questions:

1. I want to drop the rows before the rows where `Timediff2 ==0.1`.
2. Add another condition, drop theses rows, unless for that row, `Start ==1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the following, first I create a top for the row just before `Timediff2 == 0.1` then I filter:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"Start": [np.NaN, 0.0, 1.0,0.0, 0.0],
                   "Timediff2": [np.NaN, 0.1, 3417, 0.1, 793]})

df["top"] = (df["Timediff2"] == 0.1).shift(-1)
df = df.loc[(df["Start"] == 1) | (df["top"] == False), :]
df = df.drop(columns="top")
```

The result is :

```
  Start  Timediff2
1    0.0        0.1
2    1.0     3417.0
3    0.0        0.1
```